# Compare arrays with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, compare

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)
>   [How to merge two arrays in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript)

There are three arrays:

```
var items = Array(523,3452,334,31,5346);
var items_used = Array(3452,31,4123);
var items_new = Array();
```

First one is general, second is the items currenly in use. Third one includes all the items from the first array, witch are not mentioned in second.

How do I remove from the first array items, witch are used in second, and write the result to the third array?

We should get `items_new = Array(523, 334, 5346)`. `3452` and `31` are removed, because they are mentioned in second array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var items = Array(523,3452,334,31,5346);
var items_used = Array(3452,31,4123);
var items_compared = Array();

    $.each(items, function(i, val){
      if($.inArray(val, items_used) < 0)
          items_compared.push(val);
    });
```

That's it

Comment: Interesting. Tryed, but it doesn't work for me. Some punctuation bug maybe?

Comment: I tested it and is working fine. Are you sure you included jquery?

Answer (score 4):

Why not a simple for loop?

```
for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++)
{
    var found = false;
    for(var k = 0; k < items_used.length; k++)
    {
       if(items_used[k] == items[j])
       {
           found = true;
           break;
       }
    }

    if(!found)
       items_compared.push(items[j]);
}
```

Comment: You didn't ask for fast. You simply asked for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

As a faster solution maybe :

```
var j, itemsHash = {};
for (j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
  itemsHash[items[j]] = true;
}
for (j = 0; j < itemsUsed.length; j++) {
  itemsHash[itemsUsed[j]] = false;
}
for (j in itemsHash) {
   if (itemsHash[j]) {
     itemsCompared.push(j);
   }
}
```

runs in O(n) time, with a little more memory.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I would make the third have all elements in the first, then loop through the second array removing all of those elements found in the first.

```
var items_compared = items;
for(int i = 0; i < items_used.length; ++i)
{
    var indx = $.inArray(items_used[i], items_compared);
    if(indx != -1)
        items_compared.splice(indx, 1);
}
```